# How to get PayPal API details

Tags: api, paypal

I have my business account setup on paypal.com
I want to include PayPal on my website but for that I require API credentials for my account.
I have gone through all my PayPal account links but there was nothing related to APIs.
I have gone through this URL https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/
But under my Selling tools I cannot see anything like API access tab.
[image]
Can anyone please help where I can find API details.

Answer (score 0):

[Log in to this link](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) with your PayPal account.  It will return your API credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your PayPal account to Premier or Business type.
Then the API access option will be displayed within your account.